# How can I dynamically import images stored in $lib within a component in Svelte?

Tags: image, dynamic, vite, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using an array of dummy data to test how I could display information from an api. In that data, I have a relative image path, for some images I've stored locally in `$lib` for simplicity in testing.

I loop through each object in this dataset, and create a component with the relative image path passed to the object. In my testing the relative paths are resolving correctly, but I'm unable to load the images dynamically.

After doing a bit of digging, it seems that this is because of the file structure and permissions with `$lib`. It seems that image import is easy to do if I use a static solution with the images, and just dynamically adjust the relative url, but I want to be able to use Vite's performance improvements when it comes to images. Indeed, Sveltekit documentation [recommends](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/images) storing images in a directory within `$lib` for this exact reason.

In the component I can manually import each image from `$lib` and it works as expected like so:

```
<script>
import img from '$lib/assets/sample-image.jpg'; 
</script>

<img src={img} />
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how I can change the import path using a dynamic prop. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
import img from '$lib/assets/{object.imageUrlProp}';
```

Or some type of direct access in the image `src` similar to how static usage would look like:

```
<img src="$lib/assets/{object.imageUrlProp}" alt="Image" />
```

But neither of these are valid syntax.

How can I dynamically import images stored in `$lib` within a component in Svelte?

Answer (score 2):

If you only provide the file name, you would need a [dynamic import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import) that has the name interpolated into it. You might have to keep the extension separate, so the bundler knows what is being imported.

```html
{#await import(`$lib/assets/${object.imageUrlProp}.jpg`) then { default: src }}
  <img {src} alt="Image" />
{/await}
```

You probably also could do a [glob import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) (with `eager`) in the parent, then you don't have to `await` and can pass the full path that can be directly handed off to the image `src`.

Should be along the lines of:

```js
const images = import.meta.glob('$lib/assets/*.jpg', { eager: true });
```

```html
<Component imgSrc={images[`$lib/assets/${object.imageName}.jpg`]} />
```

(The image path map could likely also be extracted to a separate module and then imported in the component. Have not tried that, though.)

Comment: This does indeed work, but requires that all my images have the same extension. For now this is not a problem, but ideally I’d like to be able to show any images from that. Also, do await and glob import impact performance? Perhaps I’m going about this in a way that doesn’t make sense?

Comment: The await is kind of pointless since it imports just a path, not the contents, it will mostly cost the time of a round trip, if the bundler does not inline the path during build. Globbing happens at build time, should not drastically affect runtime as long as you don't have thousands of pictures. You can use multiple patterns to support different [locations/extensions](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#multiple-patterns).